# "After n years" or "n years down the line"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

*I am planning to work at a firm X and **after 5 years down the line** I would like to work at Y.*

Is **after 5 years down the line** grammatically correct or it should be just *"after 5 years"* or *"5 years down the line"* instead?

Comment: "5 years down the line" will do it! Don. Oh, and you can drop the "a" before "firm X", too.

Comment: Down what line?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the "after" *in combination with* "down the line" as it's redundant.
Either of the two alternatives you proposed are OK.
As rhetorician noted, you also don't need the *a* before "firm X" if X is a specific firm.

Answer (score 2):

**"I am planning to work at X for five years, then I hope to move on to Y"** would be one acceptable way to phrase your statement. "After five years down the line" is grammatically OK but not particularly idiomatic to a native English speaker.